# indexOf, search up the string instead of down

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

I'm looking for javascript in particular but I guess the problem is the same in any language. The indexOf function allows us to specify what we are looking for and where to start. It then searches down the string from the start position. Is there a way to search up the string?

IE in pseudo code:

```
str = "Hello this is a string, this is how I would like to search this string."

str.indexOf(lookFor = "this", startPosition = indexOf(how), lookUp = true)
```

In this case the function should return the "this" that is **just before "how"**. It's not the one at the start of the string, or it's not the one after "how".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search before `"how"`, slice :

```
str.slice(0, str.indexOf("how")).indexOf("this")
```

If you want to get the last occurrence of a string before "how", combine it with [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) :

```
str.slice(0, str.indexOf("how")).lastIndexOf("this")
```

Comment: @UFL1138 You're right, I completed (and edited and did a +1 to your answer, although it was only half the answer and just a link).

Answer (score 1):

Use [lastIndexOf(string[,int])](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp).

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this was downvoted as it is a correct answer.

Comment: he want the first index after split on some 'string' value ... your solution will give the last index... Check the accepted answer ... that is correct

Comment: According to the question, he's looking for a function like iindexOf but searches the other direction. That's lastIndexOf.